# Compose navigation argument string includes curly braces?

Tags: android, navigation, arguments, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable in my `NavigationHost` class that I use to navigate to a `NotesScreen()` looking like this:

```
composable(
        route = NotesScreen.route + "/{$USER_ID_KEY}"
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        NotesScreen(
            navController = navController,
            userId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(USER_ID_KEY)
        )
    }
```

The issue is when I read the `userId` string inside the `NotesScreen()` function, it still includes the curly braces as part of the passed argument string, like `"{NIsKtJ4QqteqSEwuMI7}"`. How can I make sure I get a clean string without the curly braces?

Comment: So where do you call `navigate`? Is it with a call to `navigate(NotesScreen.route + "/" + userId)` or did you add curly braces there?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. This is what I call in another screen to navigate: `navController.navigate(NotesScreen.route + "/{$userId}")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
navController.navigate(NotesScreen.route + "/{$userId}")
```

Your final string looks something like

```
notes/{NIsKtJ4QqteqSEwuMI7}
```

It seems your code is purposefully adding an extra `{` and `}`, which then get matched to your pattern of

```
notes/{userId}
```

e.g., everything after the `NotesScreen.route` is used as the `userId` - the curly braces indicate the location of the [placeholder](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) for your `userId` argument.

So if you don't want to add extra braces to your `userId`, don't add them when you call `navigate`:

```
navController.navigate(NotesScreen.route + "/$userId")
```

Comment: Worked perfect. And I got an answer from Ian Lake himself! :) Thank you!